# I want to replace auto-desk forge toolbar with my custom toolbar in viewer

Tags: c#, jquery, autodesk-forge

Is there any possibilities to create a custom toolbar instead of Auto-desk forge toolbar with functionalities?.
show me a client side code (jQuery) for the functional

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can - you can start the Viewer in headless mode (w/o the toolbar) and throw in your own instead - see details [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/headless/):

```
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(container) // instead of GuiViewer3D
```

And you see more on creating your own toolbar by extending Viewer's native UI components [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/extension-skeleton-toolbar-docking-panel).